# KIF - Integration with CI

Tags: ios, kif

With the earlier KIF, I can add testcontroller header file in appdelegate's didFinishLaunching method and my CI would work.

testcontroller.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "KIFTestController.h"

@interface testcontroller : KIFTestController

@end
```

testcontroller.m

```
#import "KIFTestScenario.h"

@implementation testcontroller

- (void)initializeScenarios;
{
    [self addScenario:[KIFTestScenario scenarioToTest]];
}

@end
```

And my app delegate would be,

```
#ifdef RUN_KIF_TESTS
//DebugLog(@"%d",testsAreRunning);
if (!testsAreRunning){
    //DebugLog(@"Run KIF Tests");
    [[testcontroller sharedInstance] startTestingWithCompletionBlock:^{
        // Exit after the tests complete so that CI knows we're done
        exit([[testcontroller sharedInstance] failureCount]);
    }];
    testsAreRunning=YES;
}

#endif
```

With new KIf (KIF-next) I don't know how to do that, because there is no controller file.

Does anyone one how to group tests in controller for new KIF structure ?

Comment: Did you check out the README of the github project (https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF)? It explains the basic setup of a KIF-test target and presents an example. If you already did check out the README, what information are you missing?

Comment: I did read it (https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF/blob/master/README.md#continuous-integration). It says it is easy to do using xcode 5 (which I don't have it yet). And it doesn't say anything about how to do it. If you have example, could you please share it with me.

Comment: You don't need Xcode 5. You have to add a test target to your project as explained in section "Create a Testing Target" of that document. Afterwards you have to define a subclass of `KIFTestCase` as explained in section "Example".

Comment: I think, I now get what you are looking for. You want to execute your kif tests on a continuous integration server like Jenkins. I have to admit that the headline is quite clear about your problem and I simply missed your point.

Comment: Yeah..I want to run my KIF tests on Jenkins and for that I need to know what changes I need to make in my test cases and appdelegate if there is any.

Comment: You don't have to make changes in the App Delegate or the test cases. You "just" have to perform the application tests. As Xcode 4 does not provide performing application tests from the console out of the box, you have to do some additional work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to execute the application test target on the continuous integration server. For example, section "The solution" of the [Setting Up Jenkins CI for iOS Development](http://axeman.in/blog/2012/12/02/setting-up-jenkins-ci-for-ios-development/) explains how you can configure pre Xcode 5 to execute the tests. Alternatively, take a look at section "Running Kiwi Specs from the Command Line" of [Continuous Integration of iOS Projects using Jenkins, CocoaPods, and Kiwi](http://9elements.com/io/index.php/continuous-integration-of-ios-projects-using-jenkins-cocoapods-and-kiwi/). Although they describe the solution for executing Kiwi tests instead of kif tests, they basically solve the same problem, namely executing an application test target using Jenkins.